# Clueless with ember-cli-postcss and autoprefixer

Tags: css, ember.js, ember-cli, postcss, autoprefixer

I'm trying to do an ember build that uses autoprefixer.
The problem that I'm having is that what normally outputs to 'assets/application-name.css' now outputs to 'app/styles/app.css' and I would like to output it to 'assets/application-name.css'.

I have tried adding the outputPaths option, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
var Funnel = require('broccoli-funnel');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    outputPaths: {
      app: {
        css: {
          'app': 'assets/application-name.css'
        }
      }
    },
    postcssOptions: {
      compile: {
        enabled: false
      },
      filter: {
        enabled: true,
        plugins: [
          {
            module: autoprefixer,
            options: {
              browsers: ['last 2 version']
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });
...
```

Comment: did you stop and restart ember server?

Comment: I did `npm run build` and restarted the application.

Comment: you might want to try https://github.com/kimroen/ember-cli-autoprefixer

Answer (score 1):

I started a project today and ran into this same issue. I has luck flipping where the autoprefixer plugin was to the `compile` step instead of the filter step.

```
/* eslint-env node */
const EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app'),
      autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    postcssOptions: {
      compile: {
        enabled: true,
        plugins: [
          {
            module: autoprefixer,
            options: {
              browsers: ['last 2 version']
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      filter: {
        enabled: false,
      }
    }
  });
  return app.toTree();
};
```

In case versions matter for this resolution:

`ember-cli: 2.12.1`

`node: 6.10.2`

`ember-cli-postcss: 3.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
outputPaths: {
  app: {
    css: {
      app: '/assets/custom-name.css'
    }
  }
},
```

Which grabs `app/styles/app.scss` and compiles it to `dist/assets/custom-name.css`.

Have you tried prepending the path with `/assets`?

---

My setup:

`ember-cli: 3.5.0`
`node: 8.11.3`
`os: darwin x64`

package.json:

```
"ember-cli": "~3.5.0",
"ember-cli-autoprefixer": "^0.8.1",
"ember-cli-sass": "^8.0.1",
"sass": "^1.14.3"
```

ember-cli-build.js:

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  const app = new EmberApp(defaults, {

    outputPaths: {
      app: {
        css: {
          app: '/assets/custom-name.css'
        }
      }
    },

    autoprefixer: {
      browsers: [
        '> 1%',
        'Explorer > 10',
        'Firefox >= 17',
        'Chrome >= 10',
        'Safari >= 6',
        'iOS >= 6'
      ],
      cascade: false,
      remove: false
    },
```